# Changing and removing the delete warning message of a query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have 2 tables: `Contacts` and `Clients`. Each record in `Clients` can have an unlimited number of related contacts. So, when I make a button to delete a client, It first deletes all related contacts, and then deletes the client itself.

Naturally, that makes it so when the button is pressed, I have to run through about 4 warning messages. I want to get rid of all these messages, and replace them with one.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: May i know that 4 warning messages.

Comment: 1. You are about to run a delete query that will modify data in your table.
2. You are about to delete 3 row(s) from the specified table //refers to related contacts
3. You are about to delete 1 record(s) //refers to clients
My bad, it was 3 warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, while RunSQL and OpenQuery start off simple, they end up causing you a lot of extra work. The OpenQuery command is really designed for displaying a SELECT or CROSSTAB query for the user to browse. For Action queries, use the Execute method to run saved queries and SQL strings:

```vb
  Dim dbs As DAO.Database
  Dim lngRowsAffected As Long
  Dim lngRowsDeleted As Long

  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  ' Execute runs both saved queries and SQL strings
  dbs.Execute cstrQueryName, dbFailOnError

  ' Get the number of rows affected by the Action query. You can
  ' display this to the user, store it in a table, or trigger an
  ' action if an unexpected # (e.g. 0 rows when you expect >0)
  lngRowsAffected = dbs.RecordsAffected
  dbs.Execute "DELETE FROM tblMyTable WHERE Bad", dbFailOnError

  lngRowsDeleted = dbs.RecordsAffected
```

You can avoid using SetWarnings because Execute doesn’t show warnings. As an added benefit, you can return the # of rows affected by the most recent action query. You can show this value to users, store it in a table, or use it to check for an unexpected result (e.g. 0 rows affected when you expect > 0).

**[Source](https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/query/action-queries/SuppressWarningMessages.htm)**

Comment: @guyuzB No problem. The real credit goes to source where i have mentioned above